# Потеря цифровой подписи.

Tags: android, eclipse

Добрый день.
В силу определенных обстоятельств потерял цифровую подпись подпись (Eclipse). Завел новую запись и подписал им приложение, но play google такое приложение не хочет принимать (предыдущие версии подписывал старой подписью). SHA1 старый мне известен. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, как выгрузить приложение в маркет. Спасибо!

Comment: ну по сути удалить это приложение?

Comment: Удалить его не получится, можно лишь снять с публикации. И затем опубликовать приложение, подписанное новым ключом (и, соответственно, с другим `package name`).

Answer (score 3):

Никак.

Отменять публикацию текущего приложения и заливать по-новой с другим id и с другим ключом.

Answer (score 3):

Если у вас осталась старая версия приложения, подписанная потерянным ключом, то этот ключ можно вытащить и пользоваться им с помощью APKTool:

1. Извлекаем META-INF из старого приложения
2. Вшиваем его в новое, ещё неподписанное приложение

**UPD** Если вы всего лишь удалили ключ с жёсткого диска и очистили корзину - не беда! Есть даже несколько вариантов восстановления:

1. Правый клик по папке, где был ключ → Предыдущие версии, там ищете версию, которая была датирована до удаления ключа, нажимаете на неё и выбираете "Восстановить". Единственный минус - всё остальное содержимое папки тоже восстановится к той дате, и если у вас там был код... В прочем, перед восстановлением вы можете заархивировать папку, чтобы избежать потерь. Итак, алгоритм таков: Архивируем папку→Восстанавливаем её старую версию→Оттуда копируем куда-нибудь ключ→Удаляем папку→Обратно разархивируем резервную копию→Вставляем туда ключ.
2. Условия те же: вы удалили ключ и очистили корзину. Была какая-то программа из комплекта TuneUp Utilities, которая может восстанавливать удалённые файлы.
3. Ключ был на внешнем носителе (флешка/внешний ЖД)? Не беда! Если с момента потери ключа прошло не больше недели, то пройдитесь по флешке программой Recuva, она тоже восстановит удалённые файлы.

Comment: Вот только `META-INF/<appname>.RSA` — публичная часть ключа, а подписывать dex/ресурсы необходимо приватным ключом. Так что, как и написал чуть выше @Suvitruf, если сертификат утерян, то ничего с этим уже не поделать, только публиковать как новое приложение.

Comment: Что за бред? Из старого приложения взять подпись ресурсов, dex файла и подсунуть в новое приложение? Ничего более бредового не слышал. Такое приложение не пройдёт валидацию при сабмите и даже если каким-то чудом оно оказалось бы на маркете - вы не сможете его установить на телефон.